# java stream toCollection ArrayList R not found

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collectors

hey i am having this problem with Collectors.`<? super Object, R>` R not found

as example :

```
Stream stream = DentityList.stream().filter(entity -> entity instanceof EntityLivingBase);
Stream streamMap = stream.<Object>map(entity -> (EntityLivingBase)entity);
```

`Stream stream1 = streamMap.<ArrayList<EntityLivingBase>, Entity>collect((Collectors.<? super Object, R>toCollection((Supplier<R>)ArrayList::new)));`

```
list type = arrayList<EntityLivingBase> (edit)
```

please help i dont get it!

Comment: Where is the `R` class defined?

Comment: On an unrelated note, why are you using raw `Stream` types (as opposed to `Stream<EntityLivingBase>`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I’m afraid we cannot help much with the information given in the question. It would be really great if you could [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use parameters in every method call, instead you should use parameters on the type declarations.

```
List<SomeClass> DentityList = new ArrayList<>();
Stream<SomeClass> stream = DentityList.stream().filter(entity -> entity instanceof EntityLivingBase);
Stream<EntityLivingBase> streamMap = stream.map(entity -> (EntityLivingBase) entity);

List<EntityLivingBase> collect = streamMap.collect((Collectors.toList()));
```

Since you didn't say what type you List consists of, I called it `SomeClass` (it obviously has to be a superclass of `EntityLivingBase`)

Also since you want to convert your `Stream` to a `List`, `Collectors.toList()` is propably more appropriate.

This way you should not have problems with unfound parameters.

Comment: its an ArrayList<EntityLivingBase>

Comment: @cleancode Then what exactly are you trying to achieve? Since every element of the Stream already is an `EntityLivingBase`, neither the filter nor the map operation will do anything. Basically you are copying the List to another List

Comment: thats what i am trying to do

Comment: @cleancode When you just want to have a new List with the same elements, there is a much simpler way:
`List<EntitiyLivingBase> newList = new ArrayList<>(DentityList);`

Comment: no i only need the entity instanceof EntityLivingBase ;D i think this is way to complex i am sry